# React Native Text Input Blur Focus on Tap Touchable

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a standard TextInput wrapped in a scrollview. When I tap outside the textinput, the focus is blurred, as expected.

However, sometimes I tap a button when inside the textinput, expecting for the button to respond immediately. However, always the first tap merely unfocuses the textinput.

Expected behavior would be for that first tap to automatically unfocus the textinput and respond to the button tap at the same time. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Could you add the code u tried to your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you need to change `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` prop of your `ScrollView` from `never` which is the default ... to `handled` ... and manually `dismiss` the keyboard on your `button` handler...

```
 <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">...</ScrollView>
```

> 'never' (the default), tapping outside of the focused text input when
> the keyboard is up dismisses the keyboard. When this happens, children
> won't receive the tap.
>
> 'always', the keyboard will not dismiss automatically, and the scroll
> view will not catch taps, but children of the scroll view can catch
> taps.
>
> 'handled', the keyboard will not dismiss automatically when the tap
> was handled by children of the scroll view (or captured by an
> ancestor).

**Edit**

```
  <ScrollView
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" // <-- here
  >
    <TextInput />
    <Button
      title="Click Me"
      onPress={() => {
        Keyboard.dismiss(); // <--- here
        Alert.alert('Button', 'Clicked!');
      }}
    />
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: how can i have both behaviors? ie tapping outside textinput dismisses keyboard, and the button will dismiss keyboard.

Comment: I’m on mobile right now, but I literally just tried what you put above, but I tried both “always” and “never”.  Each has one part of the functionality I need, but not both